# Azure Web Application Architecture

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, ssl, azure, azure-web-roles

I am building a webapplication which will be deployed on Microsoft Azure.
Part of my site will be SSL protected and the rest will not. 
I am not interested in SSL securing my entire site.
The SSL secured area includes a member login section and a create new member page. 
The rest of the webappication is just company presentation etc. and needs not be protected.

I would like to host my webapplication in a single webrole.

How should I organize my application?

Comment: Enable SSL for the whole site. For pages that require SSL, requests that come in on HTTP you could redirect to HTTPS. The other pages could accept either, you just provide links to the HTTP endpoint. The RequireSSL attribute will do the redirect for you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.requiressl.aspx

Comment: Richard, you should use this as an answer :)

Comment: I agree with Richard. I would also like to add that as a matter of performance there is no loss in doing it as Richard suggests.That is a pretty common misconception. The only performance loss is the first use of ssl, then its just water under the bridge :)